# How do I remove nav underline on hover from Bootstrap theme?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I went into the css and removed all of the text-decoration:underline but for some reason it's still showing up. Can somebody please tell me how to remove the top navigation underline when you hover over the nav?

Here is a link to the Oleose theme.

http://www.scoopthemes.com/templates/Oleose/Freeze/

Comment: you can override it with a more specific selector. Can you put in your html markup ?

Comment: I tried adding inline css style="text-decoration:none;" to override it but the underline still shows up. This is why I assumed that the theme might be text-decoration through JavaScript. You can download the theme html with the link I provided in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the culprit. It's a pseudo-element (:after) that makes the underline under the link.

```
header .navbar-default ul.navbar-nav li a:hover:after {
  background: #ffffff;
}
```

Just remove this or set background to transparent.
Or even better remove this one too.

```
header .navbar-default ul.navbar-nav li a:after{
    ....
}
```

Here is the style made for the underline.

Comment: that's probably the longest css selector I have ever seen. Why can't he just add a modifier class ?

Comment: @amin That's a selector that exists in his css. This should be removed instead of overwritten.

Comment: @TeeDeJee Thank you! I removed the two css styles and the underline is now gone :)

Answer (score 0):

So you understand what's going on there: The "underline" you are referring to is created as a pseudo element `:after` on the link itself. It is even there if you do not mouseover the link, it's just that in that state it has a transparent background-color so you cannot see it. On `:hover` the background-color of this pseudo element is changed to `#ffffff` and thus the element becomes visible. This is done in a transition fashion so it doesn't change abruptly, but softly.

This is the rule that makes the "underline" visible:

```
header .navbar-default ul.navbar-nav li a:hover:after {
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

If you change it to

```
header .navbar-default ul.navbar-nav li a:hover:after {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

it will stay invisible also when `:hover` happens. And you can always go there later and reactivate it if necessary!

Comment: Wow! That is pretty amazing @connexo, thank you so much for the great explanation. I did not understand the problem correctly. I assumed that the hover action actually generated the underline.

Comment: If your question is answered now, you should click the checkmark next to the answer that you liked best/best solved your problem. @TeeDeJee was faster, but explaining stuff takes its time. Its upon you to decide.

Comment: So you chose the faster and less detailed answer, which is perfecty fine with. If you could at least give my answer an upvote (marking it helpful)?

Comment: I can't give upvotes because I'm new to the community. I will give you an upvote as soon as I can. Thanks again! Sorry, although I benefited more from you answer, @TeeDeJee's response was faster.